# I need to operate this loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, iteration, literate-programming

```
function stainless_steel(~,~,~)
clear,clc
T_i = [0 0 12.5 25 37.5 50 0];
k = 0.0162;
cp = 0.5;
rho = 8000;
dt = 3;
dx = 0.0125;
t = 120;
q = 20000;
    
Fo = (k*dt)/(((dx)^2)*rho*cp);
e_gen = q*(dt)/(rho*cp);
n = t/dt;
p = n;
T = zeros(n,7);
    
for iteration = 1:p
    
    for x = 2:6
     
     T(iteration,x) = [Fo*(T_i(1,x+1)+273.15 + T_i(1,x-1)+273.15) + (T_i(1,x)+273.15)*(1-2*Fo) + e_gen - 273.15];
    end
    
end
T_i = T;
disp(T)
end
```

I'm getting this as a result:

```
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
     0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0
```

But what I need is the matrix T_i to change each time. For example, if T_i at the beginning was

[0 0 12.5 25 37.5 50 0]

I need my second T_i to be

[ 0   15.9720   27.5000   40.0000   52.5000   60.1400         0]

which is the result I got from the original T_i

And my third T_i to be whatever result I get from the second T_i being T_i and so on for 40 iterations.
But I don't know how to achieve that :(

Comment: You calculate the exact same thing for each row, because your computation doesn’t depend on `iteration` and nothing else is changed in your loop. You might want to move the `T_i = T;` line to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by using the the following lines:

```
T_i = zeros(n,7);
T_i(1,:) = [0 0 12.5 25 37.5 50 0];

for iteration = 1:p-1
    
    for x = 2:6
        T_i(iteration+1,x) = [Fo*(T_i(iteration,x+1)+273.15 + T_i(iteration,x-1)+273.15) + (T_i(iteration,x)+273.15)*(1-2*Fo) + e_gen - 273.15];
    end
    
end
```

This makes sure that for every row you go down in your matrix, the information of the row above is used as input. I defined it as T_i but you might want to change that as it suggests that it is the initial value. The actual initial value in my example is `T_i(1,:)`